# A shell function to copy files and directories, preserving directory structure

Tags: bash, shell

For a script, I came up with a shell function that might be generally useful. Before I add it to the code base, I’d like to hear someone’s opinion on this.

I don’t write shell scripts often and had to look up a lot of things.

The idea of this function is to copy stuff from a source folder to a destination folder with the same folder structure above the source folder, but – in contrast to e.g. `rsync`, only select files or folders.

```bash
# Copy files with parent directories to a destination
# $1: Source root directory
# $2: Source relative path(s) to be copied; may be single files or directories; may contain wildcards; may contain '..', but not to undo Source root.
# $3: Destination root directory
dircp() {
    if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
        echo 'Error: Too few arguments.'
        echo "Hint: Use"
        echo "    dircp . '<relpath1>' '<relpath2>' ... <destination>"
        echo "to copy from the current directory."
        return 1
    fi
    if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
        echo "Error: Source root directory $1 does not exist (or is not a directory)."
        return 1
    fi
    if [ ! -d ${!#} ]; then
        echo "Error: Destination root directory $3 does not exist (or is not a directory)."
        return 1
    fi
    impl() {
        srcroot=$1
        dstroot=${!#}
        for srcpath in ${@:2:$#-2}; do
            if ! ls -d "$srcpath" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "Path $srcpath does not exist!"
                return 1
            fi
            dstpath="$dstroot/${srcpath#$srcroot/}"
            if ! (mkdir -p $(dirname "$dstpath") && cp -r "$srcpath" "$dstroot/${srcpath#$srcroot/}"); then
                break
            fi
        done
    }
    for srcpath in ${@:2:$#-2}; do
        impl $1 $1/$srcpath ${!#} # expands unexpanded wildcards in $2
    done
}
```

For example:

```bash
dircp src 'a/b/c/*.txt' dst
```

copies the text files in `src/a/b/c` to `dst/a/b/c` and notably creates `a`, `b`, and/or `c` if they’re not present. Only `dst` has to be present. Multiple relative paths can be passed.

---

Probably one thing that can be improved is `if ! ls -d "$srcpath" > /dev/null 2>&1; then` to test if the file exists. I tried `if [ ! -a "$srcpath" ]; then`, but then I *need* quotes around the second argument of `dircp`, when they should be largely optional.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to.

Answer (score 6):

## UI / design

I respectfully reject the premise that this is an improvement on `rsync`.

For an "easy" copy, almost any tool will be adequate,
including `cp -r` and `tar cf - . | (cd /some/where && tar xvf -)` --
that second one works well with `ssh` pipelines.

But sometimes we need to worry about network mounts and "big" files.
In which case the twin spectres of "disk full" and CTRL/C interrupt are ever present.
In such cases, I tend to strongly value the fact that rsync
never exposes a partial copy to the destination filesystem.
It (roughly) will copy ReadMe as .123tmpReadMe, and do
an atomic [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/2/rename)
after all the bits have arrived.

That said, I do confess that rsync's distinction between
directory `foo` and `foo/` takes some getting used to,
so I *would* encourage writing a bash frontend script
which accepts whatever you feel would be an improved
syntax, and then issues an rsync command to get the work done,
revealing the command line args being used.

## relative paths

```
# $2: Source relative path(s) to be copied; may be single files or directories; may contain wildcards; may contain '..', but not to undo Source root.
```

Thank you for writing such documentation comments, I appreciate it.

I'm afraid I failed to understand the meaning of "not to undo Source root".
I initially parsed it as a security related item, don't go above Source root?
But that doesn't seem relevant for a command line tool invoked by a trusted user.

Examples wouldn't hurt,
such as confirming that a `**` recursive wildcard is supported.

The whole plural aspect of jamming "paths" and "files" into
the `$2` parameter seems unfortunate.
Usual unix approach would be to put them at the end,
so we can have one or more without worrying about quoting details.

### chdir

Maybe it's my limited imagination?
But I can't imagine why I would want that mandatory `$1` argument.

Often I want bash TAB completion of pathnames,
so I `cd` to the source directory, and now the command becomes `dircp .`

Or maybe I don't need completion,
so I type `(cd /some/where && cp foo /baz)`.
For makefiles that works out to `make -C /some/where  target`;
consider adopting an optional `-C dir` argument for dircp.

## shebang

I assume you issued `$ chmod a+x dircp`.
That should always go hand-in-hand with an initial
[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
For example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
```

Also acceptable: `#! /bin/bash`

## ls antipattern

```
            if ! ls -d "$srcpath" ...
```

This crops up often enough that [FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) pages are devoted to it.

I imagine that `[ -e "$srcpath" ]` would suffice.
Consult the [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)
man page for details.
(Kudos for getting the quoting correct here!)

## quoting

In my opinion, `bash` is not an easy language to author solid code in.
There's a lot of details, and punctuation.
Starting with quoting nonsense.

Please understand that `echo "a b" c`
is very different from `echo a b c`.
Alas, it is all too easy for a SPACE embedded within a filename to be lost
in that way.
So we kind of have to be paranoid about quoting everything,
and `shellcheck` can help.
Anything submitted to CodeReview should have already gone through
a relevant linter and passed it cleanly.
Here's the results I obtained.

```
In dircp.sh line 14:
    if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
              ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
    if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then


In dircp.sh line 25:
        for srcpath in ${@:2:$#-2}; do
                       ^---------^ SC2068 (error): Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.


In dircp.sh line 30:
            dstpath="$dstroot/${srcpath#$srcroot/}"
                                        ^------^ SC2295 (info): Expansions inside ${..} need to be quoted separately, otherwise they match as patterns.

Did you mean: 
            dstpath="$dstroot/${srcpath#"$srcroot"/}"


In dircp.sh line 31:
            if ! (mkdir -p $(dirname "$dstpath") && cp -r "$srcpath" "$dstroot/${srcpath#$srcroot/}"); then
                           ^-------------------^ SC2046 (warning): Quote this to prevent word splitting.
                                                                                         ^------^ SC2295 (info): Expansions inside ${..} need to be quoted separately, otherwise they match as patterns.

Did you mean: 
            if ! (mkdir -p $(dirname "$dstpath") && cp -r "$srcpath" "$dstroot/${srcpath#"$srcroot"/}"); then


In dircp.sh line 36:
    for srcpath in ${@:2:$#-2}; do
                   ^---------^ SC2068 (error): Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.


In dircp.sh line 37:
        impl $1 $1/$srcpath ${!#} # expands unexpanded wildcards in $2
             ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                ^-- SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                   ^------^ SC2086 (info): Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: 
        impl "$1" "$1"/"$srcpath" ${!#} # expands unexpanded wildcards in $2

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2068 -- Double quote array expansions to ...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2046 -- Quote this to prevent word splitt...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2086 -- Double quote to prevent globbing ...
```

Recommend you tidy those up,
and then come back for a second pass.

Comment: Using shellcheck is indeed a must-do, I would even recommend adding it as a git hook upon commit.

Comment: “Recommend you tidy those up, and then come back for a second pass.” How am I supposed to do that when my edits were reverted? (I’m rather new to this.)

Comment: Sure, I understand, the site takes some getting used to. The [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) can help: "_I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?_"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @J_H that you essential try to reimplement a solved problem. In particular, you should take a look into the `--include` and `--exclude` options of `tar`.

That being said, there are quite a few general things which can be said about your script, whereas I'll skip what was already mentioned by @J_H.

```bash
    if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
```

If you can assume that this is indeed run by `bash`, I'd always prefer a conditional command over a test command, because it has less quoting issues and easier syntax. E.g. while `shellcheck` will point out quoting issues for `[ ! -d $1 ]` there is no such issue for `[[ ! -d $1 ]]`. And for the above you could write `[[ $# < 3 ]]` which is arguably more readable.

On the other hand, if you want to support other shells, you may have to keep the test commands and carefully quote everything.

```bash
        echo 'Error: Too few arguments.'
        echo "Hint: Use"
        echo "    dircp . '<relpath1>' '<relpath2>' ... <destination>"
        echo "to copy from the current directory."
        return 1
```

This is clearly error output and should be redirected to stderr by redirecting each `echo` via `>&2`. You can also group the echos together, so you don't have to repeat the redirect in each line:

```bash
        {
            echo 'Error: Too few arguments.'
            echo "Hint: Use"
            echo "    dircp . '<relpath1>' '<relpath2>' ... <destination>"
            echo "to copy from the current directory."
        } >&2
```

The same thing applies of course for the other error messages. In general, not only error messages should be redirected to stderr, but any kind of diagnostic messages which are not part of the main output of the program.

```bash
    if [ ! -d ${!#} ]; then
        echo "Error: Destination root directory $3 does not exist (or is not a directory)."
```

The error message doesn't match the test. Also, I don't think I ever saw referencing the last parameter via `${!#}`, I think using `${@: -1}` is more idiomatic.

```bash
    impl() {
```

There is no such thing as a 'local' function in bash. You're essentially defining this function anew on each `dircp` call and leaking it to the current shell namespace. Instead, it's more idiomatic if you define it outside of `dircp` and prefix its name with `__` to indicate that it's not meant to be called directly. (It should get a better name than `impl` though.)

Alternatively, you could wrap the function definition and its call in a subshell via `( ... )`. But while that works and doesn't leak anything, I'm afraid it isn't very idiomatic.

The best solution would probably be to get rid of enclosing `dircp` function and just make an executable script called `dircp` with a proper shebang line, as @J_H already indicated. Having a function is useful if you need to modify the current shell environment, but I don't see that use case here.

```bash
        srcroot=$1
        dstroot=${!#}
```

These should be declared as `local` otherwise they leak outside. I'd even use `local -r` here, since you don't need to reassign them.

```bash
        for srcpath in ${@:2:$#-2}; do
```

[Also loop variables should be declared local](https://leogtzr.medium.com/yes-you-also-need-to-use-local-on-loop-control-variables-68c2e59800fd), otherwise they are leaking.

```bash
        impl $1 $1/$srcpath ${!#} # expands unexpanded wildcards in $2
```

Seems you missed an opportunity here to reorder the arguments to make your life a little easier. Since `impl` is only an internal helper function, you can change the signature at will and pass the last argument as second. I.e.

```bash
        impl "$1" "${@: -1}" $1/$srcpath  # expands unexpanded wildcards in $2
```

Then within `impl` you can do a `shift 2` before the `for` loop, which means you don't have to repeat the ugly `${@:2:$#-2}` since all loop items are in `$@` now (which are the default items for `for`).